# RTC DS1307 3.3V I2C and Oscilloscope impedance

Tags: i2c, stm32, oscilloscope, rtc, 3.3v

I'm working on a library for STM32 to learn I2C protocol (Software I2C, not hardware).

I connect my DS1307 (Sparkfun [BOB-12708](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12708)) : ([Here is the module schematic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/RTC-Module.v14.pdf)) :

- I remove welding on the SJ2 jumper to dont use 4.7K embedded module pullup resistors.
- I supply 5v power to the module
- My STM32 board already has 4.7K pullup resistors to 3.3V
- I connect module SDA and SCL to my STM32 3.3V GPIO with 15 cm cables.
- I connect my two way oscilloscope to SDA and SCL.

I can produce a nice SCL (100KHz) and SDA signal except for the I2C "START CONDITION", SDA take time to fall down, the falling edge is not straightforward.
When I increase timing in my code I can get the DS1307 address ACK. So I suspected the resistors values not be appropriate.

I used two different GPIO without pullup resistors and I use my own 1K pullup resistors to 3.3V and this work very well. Signal is nice I can read and write successfully to DS1307 and get date/time.

So I disconnect my oscilloscope, but after that, I could not read or write to the device :(. My oscilloscope impedance is 1M. If I leave 1K pullup resistor to 3.3V AND put a 1M resistor to ground this work.

I also try with bi-directional logic level converter (BOB-12009) and this work well but I want to use DS1307 directly without converter.

- Can someone help me to understand why I need this 1M resistor ?
- What 3.3V pullup resistors value can I use to only use pullup ?

***Edit:***

- STM32 board is an Olimex STM32F103STK
- Ground is connected between STM32, DS1307 (and oscilloscope when i plug it)

***Edit 2:***

My cable got bad ground wire connector, i replace the connector and now all work fine with or without oscilloscope and with 4.7K or 1K pullup resistors to 3.3V. Empirically 2.2K seem to be a good trade-off between current and clean signal edges.

Comment: Which STM32 module are you using? Are you connecting GND between the STM32 and the DS1307?

Comment: Adam, thanks for reading. Yes ground is connected between STM32 and DS1307.

Comment: Too high pull-up resistor would make rising edge slower, not falling. Are you sure you are in open-drain output mode?

Comment: Adam look right, this is a ground problem on câble. Problem solved with good cable... sorry to disturbe